# GitVersion.yml file understanding

Tags: git, version, devops, gitversion

```
branches:
  main:
    regex: ^master$|^main$
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  release:
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    pre-release-weight: 1000
  feature:
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  pull-request:
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)[-/]'
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  hotfix:
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  support:
    regex: ^support[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  develop:
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: unstable
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
```

Can someone explain the GitVersion.yml file.How it works.ALso I dont want to create release with betaxxxx.I just wanted to release the version with only number like 1.1.2/1.1.3.
What changes I have to make in this GitVersion file?

Comment: https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/configuration

Answer (score 8):

According to your `gitversion.yml` file, the only releasable branch is `release` branch.

The semver you get from every commit from those release branches will have a `beta` tag added. Even if you name your release branch like `releases/v1.2.3`, you will get `1.2.3-beta.someNumber`.

To get semver `1.2.3`, you must make a git tag to the commit in your `release` branch, `v1.2.3`. GitVersion recognizes that the commit has a git tag, and will use the version in the git tag as semver.

This behavior is fulfilled by a default gitversion configuration: `tag-prefix: '[vV]'`, which is not present in your yml file. You can find this config in the complete list of configuration GitVersion use on top of your `gitversion.yml` file, with `gitversion -showconfig` or `dotnet gitversion -showconfig`, for whichever way you have gitversion installed.

- On a git tagged commit, gitversion bypasses lots of branch specific configurations specified in `gitversion.yml`.

Read more here: https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/configuration

Comment: so you have to create tag yourself?